# ReactJS - How to exclude disabled form items from request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Form` block with several `Collapse.Panel` sub-blocks. The `Form.Item` nodes in panels that are left collapsed are not included among the form values when a form submit request is made. But within a panel, some `InputNumber` fields that are conditionally disabled are still showing up in the submit request with a value of `undefined`. This is causing some deserialization and parsing issue on the python backend that I'm hoping to resolve by excluding disabled nodes completely from the submit request.

I've tried working with `defaultValue`, passing `''`, `null`, and `0`. But still not getting quite the result sought after here, i.e. skipping disabled nodes in submit request.

This might be a question of how best to deserialize the values in the xhr request passed to backend, but want to first check if there is an option in React or JS.

For example:

```
<Panel header="ExamplePanel" key="1">
    <Form.Item name="ExampleItem" label="Form Item">
        <InputNumber
            defaultValue={''}
            min={0}
            disabled={true} //setting to true here for simplification
        />
    </Form.Item>
</Panel>
```

When submitting the form that includes the snippet above, the request includes `ExampleItem` with a value of `undefined`.

Is there a way to exclude disabled fields/nodes completely from form values similar to the way fields/nodes in collapsed panels are left out?

Answer (score 0):

What's the mechanism for submitting the form here? I'm inferring based on your post that you're relying on default `<form>` element behavior combined with a `<button type="submit">`?

If you want to accomplish this in the client with react, you'll want to turn this into a "controlled" form and write your own `onSubmit` handler, in which you can include or omit whichever bits of form data you please before actually  `POST`ing the data to the server.

See the react docs for more info:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Would recommend adding your question "What's the mechanism for submitting the form..." as a comment to the OP (Original Poster) question. Then clarify that your answer assumes a particular setup, before submitting an _example of how to fix the problem_, rather than just a link. e.g. a sample onSubmit handler, with the link at bottom for context.